# cmake project() unsets UNIX

Tags: cmake

I had an issue today with cmake where UNIX is unset by the project statement.

```
message("before ${UNIX}")
project (MyProj VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
message("after ${UNIX}")
```

Gives the output:

```
before 1
after
```

I am using WSL2 with cmake version 3.24.0-rc3.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I rolled cmake back to V3.22.5 and this problem immediately went away.  I will raise an issue on cmake.